# Deserialize to dynamic enum with Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, json-deserialization

I have a Pojo that looks something like this

```
public class MyObject {
private MyEnum enum
}
```

And it works fine for de-serializing a Json object where the string value of 'enum' (in the Json) is a valud enum object.

Now, I have a new requirement that requires the enum to be determined dynamically.  In other words, I have 2 types of MyObjects.  They each use a different set of enum values.  So I now have 2 enums, `MyEnum1` and `MyEnum2`.  When I read in a Json object, I know which type it is. Since an Enum class can't really be instantiated, I don't think I can use a factory method to determine which one to use.  But not sure how to handle the de-serialization.  I thought of using a generic, such as

```
public class MyObject<T> {
private T enum
}
```

But that doesn't really work since generics can't be specified at runtime.

Is there some other solution?

Comment: It's kind of strange to have 2 different enums for the same object, can't they be merged? Or maybe is wrapping them in a typed object a acceptable workaround (since it won't rely on genericity then)

Comment: They have some values in common, but essentially have different lists of valid values.  Other than that, the objects are the same.   I'll have to think about wrapping in a typed object.  That might work.

Comment: If you need polymorphism with standard classes, you can use  annotations that's add class name in a custom property: `@JsonTypeInfo` + `@JsonSubTypes`

Comment: Do you have control over the classes/enums? Can you change them at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is missing some context about how the enum field is used, but assuming you can alter the classes/enums, one solution could be to use an interface that both `MyEnum1` and `MyEnum2` implement. Like this:

```java
public interface MyEnumType {
}

public enum MyEnum1 implements MyEnumType {
}

public enum MyEnum2 implements MyEnumType {
}

public class MyObject {

    private MyEnumType myEnum;
}
```

With that basic structure, we can use Jackson's `@JsonTypeInfo` and `@JsonSubStypes` annotations to achieve polymorphism in serialization/deserialization. Here's the annotated interface:

```java
@JsonTypeInfo(use = Id.NAME)
@JsonSubTypes({ @Type(MyEnum1.class), @Type(MyEnum2.class) })
public interface MyEnumType {
}
```

Here is how I test that it's working:

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;


@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class MyObject {

    @JsonProperty
    private MyEnumType myEnum;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Enum value is " + myEnum;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper jsonMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        MyObject original = new MyObject(MyEnum1.Blue);
        //MyObject original = new MyObject(MyEnum2.Triangle);
        String json = jsonMapper.writeValueAsString(original);

        MyObject result = jsonMapper.readValue(json, MyObject.class);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

**Important note: this solution assumes that you can control the JSON format *and* both serialization and deserialization.**

If you can not alter the JSON format or control the serialization side, you can instead use `@JsonCreator` to write a factory method that converts from the string JSON value to a matching instance of `MyEnumType`. For example, something like this:

```java
public interface MyEnumType {

    @JsonCreator
    public static MyEnumType deserailize(String value) {
        MyEnumType result = null;

        try {
            result = MyEnum1.valueOf(value);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {}

        if (result == null) {
            try {
                result = MyEnum2.valueOf(value);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {}
        }

        if (result == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(value + " does not match any known enum.");
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

This is a somewhat naive implementation; if you have more enum types you probably would want to make the implementation a little cleaner than just repeating the same `try...catch` again and again. But this should give a good starting point.

Comment: Yes, I do control everything.  How does this determine which Enum implementation to use?  It looks like it will match any value, whether it's in MyEnum1 or MyEnum2, correct?  What is the `@JsonProperty` annotation for?  I usually only use that if I have to change the name of the property.  Does it do something else with no argument?

Comment: You should display the json `{"myEnum":["MyEnum1","Blue"]}` so the enum is stored as an array typename, value: ["MyEnum1","Blue"], on reading the parser reads the type as first arguments then known which enum to implement

Comment: I should qualify my statement "I control everything".  Assume that I do not control the Json. I know what format it will be in before I read it, but I can't add that additional qualifirt to the enum value

Comment: I updated the answer with an alternative for situations where you don't control the serialization (and thus can't rely on Jackson's type information metadata being included).